# write XML through Editor GUI

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I've got an XML file with the following Nodes:

```
<Products>
   <Product name="Test 1">
        <title>Test1 Title</title>
        <content>Lorem ipsum....... </content>
        <facebook>
            <fb-picture>Here goes a link</fb-picture>
            <fb-caption>This is a caption</fb-caption>
           <fb-description>This is a description</fb-description>
        </facebook>
    </Product>
<Products>
```

Now I would like to make a copy from "Product" and fill all innerTexts through an EditorGUI. 
Because I will get a lot of Products in this XML and I don't want to fill all those texts via the XML file.

I am kinda lost and don't now where to start.
I work with Unity4.6 and C#.

Hope someone can tell me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You start by learning how to make a xml write [this might help](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter)

Comment: Thank you, I solved it by using this example:
http://purdyjotut.blogspot.de/2013/10/unity-editor-tools-and-xml-to-save-time.html

Comment: Then you can answer your own question. Describe what you did to fix the problem and how the link helped and when you can accept your own answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I've used the following example:
http://purdyjotut.blogspot.de/2013/10/unity-editor-tools-and-xml-to-save-time.html

First I've made a new class where I put in all my strings (or fields) I need

```
public class ProductItems {
    public string name = string.Empty;
    public string text = string.Empty;
    public string tags = string.Empty;
    public string pictureName = string.Empty;
    public string pictureURL = string.Empty;
    public string caption = string.Empty;
    public string description = string.Empty;
    public string url = string.Empty;
}
```

After that I've created the class from the example link

```
public class ItemsEditor (){}
```

I changed all item field names to the ones I've created in my ProductItems class.

This class will create an Editor window where I can add or remove Items to my XML file.

The output xml will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<ArrayOfProductItems xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <ProductItems>
   <name>This is a name</name>
   <text>This is a text</text>
   <tags>Test Tag1</tags>
   <pictureName>pictureName</pictureName>
   <pictureURL>www.pictureURL.com</pictureURL>
   <caption>Test caption</caption>
   <description>Test description</description>
   <url>www.test.de</url>
 </ProductItems>
</ArrayOfProductItems>
```

Still, I've got one problem left, I could not figure out yet how to add a name field in the "ProductItems" attribute like this:

```
<ProductItems name="Item 1">
```

Maybe someone else does know this?